# How to convert an array to multiple array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array abc = [1, 2, 3].

How can i convert it to multiple arrays: [1, 2] , [1, 3], [2, 3]

Note: If abc have n items, we will convert to n*(n-1) arrays

Comment: what about `4`? what have you tried?

Comment: Going by your quetion thjere should be 6 arrays, but you have only mentioned 3 can you mention other 3 also so we know the pattern.

And please add the code that you have tried as your effort.

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake, it should [1, 2, 3]. I changed it

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
const combinations = arr =>
    arr.flatMap((elX, indexX) =>
        arr
            .filter((_, indexY) => indexY == indexX)
            .map(elY => [elX, elY])
    )
```

the result will be n*(n-1) so for [1,2,3] = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to list all kind of combination to be made from original array
you can run code below in console to check if it fits your needs

Note that in code below, i use filter to avoid same value in the same array group
Sorry for my bad english

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr = arr.map((currentValue, index, arr)=>{
    return arr.filter((val2, idx2) => val2 !== currentValue);
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr,null,4));
```

Edit: i know the question wants 6 arrays, this code above is following the example he gave... This is alternative answer if what he really meant was to find every single unique combination (without mirror effect)

Comment: This gives 3 arrays, not 6 as requested.

Comment: Yes it gives 3 arrays, but i was following his example of 1 2 3, and found that maybe he doesn't want any mirror combination... So i gave this one,, but if he really wants the 6 arrays he just needs to choose other answer that can answer his question perfectly, but thanks for commenting 